# How can I change Settings.MinSimilarity in Sikuli?

Tags: java, automated-tests, sikuli

I took screenshots in my manual test, then in automated part I use `find()` method in `Region.java` class. I want to change `Settings.MinSimilarity` which has default value of `0.7`. For my automated test I need the value of `0.9`. `Settings.java` class is read-only class. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just import `Settings` class:

```
import org.sikuli.basics.Settings;
```

Then, in your code (in constructor), initialize `MinSimilarity` value:

```
public TestClass() {
    Settings.MinSimilarity = 0.9;
}
```

Comment: @nehiridil if answer was helpful, please, mark it as right answer. thanks.